# Unable to drop column through type-orm migration

Tags: sql, node.js, postgresql, express, typeorm

I have a test entity, with a `creatorId` field which was initially of type `integer`, after changing it to `string` and running the migration it was still of type `int` so I completely removed the field and added another field `userId` and ran the migration, this time it added the `userId` column but didn't remove the creatorId column.

**Test entity:**

```
@ObjectType()
@Entity()
export class Test extends BaseEntity {
  @Field()
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id!: number;

  @Field(() => String)
  @Column()
  creatorId: string; // problem here

  @ManyToOne(() => User, (user) => user.tests)
  creator: User;

  @Field()
  @Column()
  time: string;

  @Field()
  @Column()
  accuracy: string;

  @Field()
  @Column()
  wpm: number;

  @Field()
  @Column()
  chars: string;

  @Field(() => String)
  @CreateDateColumn()
  createdAt: Date;
}
```

**scripts**

```
"scripts": {
    "watch": "tsc -w",
    "dev": "nodemon dist/index.js",
    "start": "node dist/index.js",
    "typeorm": "ts-node ./node_modules/typeorm/cli",
    "migration:create": "typeorm migration:create ./src/migrations/migration",
    "migration:run": "ts-node ./node_modules/typeorm/cli --dataSource ./dist/data-source.js migration:run",
    "migration:generate": "ts-node ./node_modules/typeorm/cli --dataSource ./dist/data-source.js migration:generate ./src/migrations/migration",
    "migration:show": "ts-node ./node_modules/typeorm/cli --dataSource ./dist/data-source.js migration:show"
  },
```

**data-source.ts**

```
import { DataSource } from 'typeorm';
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
import { User } from './entities/user';
import { Test } from './entities/test';

dotenv.config();

export const AppDataSource = new DataSource({
  type: 'postgres',
  host: 'localhost',
  port: 5432,
  database: 'type-io',
  username: process.env.DATABASE_USERNAME?.toString(),
  password: process.env.DATABASE_PASSWORD?.toString(),
  logging: true,
  synchronize: false,
  entities: [Test, User],
  migrations: [],
  cache: false,
});

AppDataSource.initialize()
  .then(async () => {
    console.log('Data Source has been initialized!');
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.error('Error during Data Source initialization', err);
  });
```

Also the reason the migrations field is empty because only when I import the migration class from the migration file it works, referencing the path didn't work

Here is an example, when I renamed the userId field to creatorId, here is the query generated:

```
import { MigrationInterface, QueryRunner } from "typeorm";

export class migration1680420345316 implements MigrationInterface {
    name = 'migration1680420345316'

    public async up(queryRunner: QueryRunner): Promise<void> {
        await queryRunner.query(`ALTER TABLE "test" DROP COLUMN "userId"`);
        await queryRunner.query(`ALTER TABLE "test" DROP CONSTRAINT "FK_ab6d476e7698322a3a35b5fdb12"`);
        await queryRunner.query(`ALTER TABLE "test" ALTER COLUMN "creatorId" SET NOT NULL`);
        await queryRunner.query(`ALTER TABLE "test" ADD CONSTRAINT "FK_ab6d476e7698322a3a35b5fdb12" FOREIGN KEY ("creatorId") REFERENCES "user"("id") ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION`);
    }

    public async down(queryRunner: QueryRunner): Promise<void> {
        await queryRunner.query(`ALTER TABLE "test" DROP CONSTRAINT "FK_ab6d476e7698322a3a35b5fdb12"`);
        await queryRunner.query(`ALTER TABLE "test" ALTER COLUMN "creatorId" DROP NOT NULL`);
        await queryRunner.query(`ALTER TABLE "test" ADD CONSTRAINT "FK_ab6d476e7698322a3a35b5fdb12" FOREIGN KEY ("creatorId") REFERENCES "user"("id") ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION`);
        await queryRunner.query(`ALTER TABLE "test" ADD "userId" character varying NOT NULL`);
    }

}
```

I think the error has something to do with `typeorm entity metadata` and maybe clearing it will fix the error, but so far I couldn't figure out how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After many hours of debugging, I figured out that the problem wasn't with `typeorm entity metadata` rather it was with which column in the `User entity` was being referenced with the `creatorId` column in the Test entity. By default the `id` field of type `integer` was being referenced so both the `creatorId` and the `id` field had to be of the same type so when the migration was being run it created creatorId field type as int. I fixed this issue by referencing the `uid` field which was of type `character varying` by modifying the entity like this:

```
@ObjectType()
@Entity()
export class Test extends BaseEntity {

  @Field()
  @Column()
  creatorId: string;

  @ManyToOne(() => User, (user) => user.tests)
  @JoinColumn({ name: 'creatorId', referencedColumnName: 'uid' })
  creator: User;
}
```